# How can I get Prawn from :git in my Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, prawn, gemspecs

This is Rails 2.3.8, I am using Bundler 1.0.21 and RubyGems 1.6.2 on a Mac.

When I do:

```
bundle install
```

I am met with:

```
"PRAWN_VERSION = \"1.0.0.rc1\"\n\nGem::Specification.new do |spec|\n  spec.name = \"prawn\"\n  spec.version = PRAWN_VERSION\n  spec.platform = Gem::Platform::RUBY\n  spec.summary = \"A fast and nimble PDF generator for Ruby\"\n  spec.files =  Dir.glob(\"{examples,lib,spec,data,manual}/**/**/*\") +\n    [\"Rakefile\", \"prawn.gemspec\", \"COPYING\", \"LICENSE\", \"GPLv2\", \"GPLv3\",\n     \"Gemfile\"]\n  spec.require_path = \"lib\"\n  spec.required_ruby_version = '>= 1.8.7'\n  spec.required_rubygems_version = \">= 1.3.6\"\n\n  spec.test_files = Dir[ \"spec/*_spec.rb\" ]\n  spec.extra_rdoc_files = %w{README.md LICENSE COPYING GPLv2 GPLv3}\n  spec.rdoc_options << '--title' << 'Prawn Documentation' <<\n                       '--main'  << 'README.md' << '-q'\n  spec.authors = [\"Gregory Brown\",\"Brad Ediger\",\"Daniel Nelson\",\"Jonathan Greenberg\",\"James Healy\"]\n  spec.email = [\"gregory.t.brown@gmail.com\",\"brad@bradediger.com\",\"dnelson@bluejade.com\",\"greenberg@entryway.net\",\"jimmy@deefa.com\"]\n  spec.rubyforge_project = \"prawn\"\n  spec.add_dependency('pdf-reader', '>=0.9.0')\n  spec.add_dependency('ttfunk', '~>1.0.3')\n  spec.add_development_dependency('pdf-inspector', '~> 1.0.1')\n  spec.homepage = \"http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com\"\n  spec.description = <<END_DESC\n  Prawn is a fast, tiny, and nimble PDF generator for Ruby\nEND_DESC\n  spec.post_install_message = <<END_DESC\n\n  ********************************************\n\n\n  A lot has changed recently in Prawn.\n\n  Please read the changelog for details:\n\n  https://github.com/sandal/prawn/wiki/CHANGELOG\n\n\n  ********************************************\n\nEND_DESC\nend\n"
syntax error on line 35, col 39: `  Please read the changelog for details:'
```

There is something about the gemspec that does not work correctly. Please help, I have had this problem for over 2 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Ruby-1.8.7-p334. The issue went away when I moved to Ruby-1.8.7-p352.